# Computer display shows no image

Tags: display, sleep, amd-radeon

A few minutes ago, I left my computer and turned off the display in order to install Unity. After about half a hour, I returned and turned on the screen. While it automatically detected VGA input, nothing appeared on screen. The computer wasn't asleep, the monitor was functional and the peripherals functioned since the "Num lock" light reacts. I finally fixed the problem by pressing the "Sleep" button on my keyboard, which sent the computer to sleep. Then I woke the computer up. After the computer awakened, the screen suddenly could display again. This has already happened before but I never found the source of the problem, any possible fixes? (Radeon Hd 7750 with latest drivers, i5, 7200RPM 1TB HDD, Windows 8.1)

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, it should say "A few minutes ago, I left my computer and turned off **the display**..." I will go fix it now

Comment: What kind of monitor?

Comment: It was the one my computer came with, but I am not sure how to find out the model.